# Error System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException(0x80131904) Error Formulario con sql

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2015

[image: Ese es el error que me tira]Quiero ayuda con un pequeño error que me esta dando un programa que estoy haciendo para mi clase, es un pequeño programa de una ferreteria donde se guardan productos, clientes(con el fin de que si es distribuidor aplicar descuento), tipos de productos etc... El problema esta en la parte de facturación unas veces me permite guardar la factura otras no, y no se que hacer, eh probado todo lo que puedo saber, pero nada, NECESITO AYUDA DE ALGUIEN, se les agradece mucho de antemano.

```
protected override void Inicializar()
{
    base.Inicializar();

    // Llenamos el comboBox de Clientes
    CargarClientes();

    if (param_codigo == 0)
    {
        // Nuevo Registro
        NuevaFactura();
    }
    else
    {
        // Registro ya Existente
        btnAdicionarProducto.Enabled = false;

        VerFactura();
    }

}

private void CargarClientes()
{
    DataTable dt = null;
    string cadena_sql = "";
    cadena_sql = @"SELECT codigo, nombre_cliente 
                   FROM Clientes ";

    if (global.conn.SQLSelectDataTable(cadena_sql, ref dt))
    {
        cmbCodigoCliente.DataSource = dt;
    }
}

private void NuevaFactura()
{
    string cadena_sql = "";
    DataRow dr = null;
    int numero_factura = 0;

    cadena_sql = @"SELECT ISNULL(max(numero_factura),0) as maximo
                   FROM Facturas";

    if (global.conn.SQLSelectDataRow(cadena_sql, ref dr))
    {
        numero_factura = Convert.ToInt32(dr["maximo"]);

        numero_factura = numero_factura + 1;

        txtNumeroFactura.Text = numero_factura.ToString();
    }

}

private void VerFactura()
{
    VerEncabezado();
    VerDetalle();
}

private void VerEncabezado()
{
    DataRow dr = null;
    string cadena_sql = "";

    cadena_sql = @"SELECT * 
                   FROM Facturas
                   WHERE codigo = {0}";

    cadena_sql = string.Format(cadena_sql, param_codigo);

    if (global.conn.SQLSelectDataRow(cadena_sql, ref dr))
    {
        txtCodigo.Text = dr["codigo"].ToString();
        txtNumeroFactura.Text = dr["numero_factura"].ToString();
        dtpFecha.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["fecha"]);
        cmbCodigoCliente.SelectedValue = Convert.ToInt32(dr["codigo_cliente"]);

        txtSubtotal.Text = Convert.ToDouble(dr["subtotal"]).ToString("###,###.00");
        txtImpuesto.Text = Convert.ToDouble(dr["impuesto"]).ToString("###,###.00");
        txtTotal.Text = Convert.ToDouble(dr["total"]).ToString("###,###.00");

    }
}
private void VerDetalle()
{
    string cadena_sql = "";
    DataTable dt = null;

    cadena_sql = @"SELECT 
                    fd.numero_linea
                    ,fd.codigo_producto
                    ,p.nombre as nombre_producto
                    ,fd.cantidad
                    ,fd.precio
                    ,(fd.cantidad * fd.precio) as total_item
                    FROM
                    FacturasDetalle fd
                    join
                    Productos p
                    on
                    fd.codigo_producto = p.codigo
                    WHERE
                    fd.codigo_factura = {0}
                    ";

    cadena_sql = string.Format(cadena_sql, param_codigo);

    if (global.conn.SQLSelectDataTable(cadena_sql, ref dt))
    {
        dgvDetalle.DataSource = dt;
    }


}


private void Totales()
{
    // Objetivo:
    // Recorrer el detalle, calcular total item
    // Sumarizar Subtotal, impuesto y total

    double cantidad = 0;
    double precio = 0;
    double total_item = 0;

    double subtotal = 0;
    double impuesto = 0;
    double total = 0;

    foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dgvDetalle.Rows)
    {
        cantidad = Convert.ToDouble(r.Cells["nCantidad"].Value);
        precio = Convert.ToDouble(r.Cells["nPrecio"].Value);

        total_item = cantidad * precio;

        r.Cells["nTotalItem"].Value = total_item;

        subtotal = subtotal + total_item;

    }

    // Calculamos impuesto y total
    impuesto = subtotal * 0.15;

    total = subtotal + impuesto;

    txtSubtotal.Text = subtotal.ToString("###,###.00");
    txtImpuesto.Text = impuesto.ToString("###,###.00");
    txtTotal.Text = total.ToString("###,###.00");


}


private void AdicionarProducto()
{
    try
    {
        int codigo_producto = 0;

        int indice_nuevo = 0;

        int numero_fila = 0;
        string nombre_producto = "";
        double precio_producto = 0;

        string cadena_sql = "";
        DataRow dr = null;

        frmProductos prods = new frmProductos();
        prods.modo_actual = frmLista.ModoApertura.Busqueda;
        prods.ShowDialog(this);

        codigo_producto = prods.codigo_seleccionado;

        if (codigo_producto > 0)
        {
            // Agregamos una fila

            cadena_sql = @"SELECT nombre, precio
                            FROM productos 
                            WHERE codigo = {0}";
            cadena_sql = string.Format(cadena_sql, codigo_producto);

            if (global.conn.SQLSelectDataRow(cadena_sql, ref dr))
            {
                nombre_producto = dr["nombre"].ToString();
                precio_producto = Convert.ToDouble(dr["precio"]);

                indice_nuevo = dgvDetalle.Rows.Add();

                dgvDetalle.Rows[indice_nuevo].Cells["nNumeroLinea"].Value = indice_nuevo + 1;
                dgvDetalle.Rows[indice_nuevo].Cells["nCodigoProducto"].Value = codigo_producto;
                dgvDetalle.Rows[indice_nuevo].Cells["sNombreProducto"].Value = nombre_producto;
                dgvDetalle.Rows[indice_nuevo].Cells["nCantidad"].Value = 1;
                dgvDetalle.Rows[indice_nuevo].Cells["nPrecio"].Value = precio_producto;

                dgvDetalle.Rows[indice_nuevo].Cells["nTotalItem"].Value = precio_producto;

                // Llamamos a la funcion de Totales
                Totales();
            }






        }



    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}

private void btnAdicionarProducto_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AdicionarProducto();
}

private void dgvDetalle_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    Totales();
}

private void frmFactura_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

protected override void AccionGuardar()
{
    if (param_codigo > 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Factura no se puede editar");
        return;
    }

    if (GuardarEncabezado())
    {
        GuardarDetalle();
    }
}

private bool GuardarEncabezado()
{
    try
    {
        DataRow dr = null;
        int codigo = 0;
        string cadena_sql = "";

        cadena_sql = @"INSERT INTO [dbo].[Facturas]
                   ([numero_factura],
                   [codigo_cliente],
                   [fecha],
                   [subtotal],
                   [impuesto],
                   [total])
             VALUES
                   (
                    {0},
                    {1},
                    '{2}',
                    {3},
                    {4},
                    {5})";


        cadena_sql = string.Format(
                    cadena_sql,
                    txtNumeroFactura.Text,
                    cmbCodigoCliente.SelectedValue,
                    dtpFecha.Value.ToString("yyyyMMdd"),
                    Convert.ToDouble(txtSubtotal.Text),
                    Convert.ToDouble(txtImpuesto.Text),
                    Convert.ToDouble(txtTotal.Text)
                    );

        if (global.conn.SqlExec(cadena_sql))
        {
            cadena_sql = @"SELECT MAX(codigo) as maximo
                           FROM Facturas";

            if (global.conn.SQLSelectDataRow(cadena_sql, ref dr))
            {
                codigo = Convert.ToInt32(dr["maximo"]);

                txtCodigo.Text = codigo.ToString();

                return true;

            }



         }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error al guardar encabezado: "
                            + global.conn.SQLError() );
        }


    }
```

protected override void Inicializar()
    {
        base.Inicializar();

```
    // Llenamos el comboBox de Clientes
    CargarClientes();

    if (param_codigo == 0)
    {
        // Nuevo Registro
        NuevaFactura();
    }
    else
    {
        // Registro ya Existente
        btnAdicionarProducto.Enabled = false;

        VerFactura();
    }

}

private void CargarClientes()
{
    DataTable dt = null;
    string cadena_sql = "";
    cadena_sql = @"SELECT codigo, nombre_cliente 
                   FROM Clientes ";

    if (global.conn.SQLSelectDataTable(cadena_sql, ref dt))
    {
        cmbCodigoCliente.DataSource = dt;
    }
}

private void NuevaFactura()
{
    string cadena_sql = "";
    DataRow dr = null;
    int numero_factura = 0;

    cadena_sql = @"SELECT ISNULL(max(numero_factura),0) as maximo
                   FROM Facturas";

    if (global.conn.SQLSelectDataRow(cadena_sql, ref dr))
    {
        numero_factura = Convert.ToInt32(dr["maximo"]);

        numero_factura = numero_factura + 1;

        txtNumeroFactura.Text = numero_factura.ToString();
    }

}

private void VerFactura()
{
    VerEncabezado();
    VerDetalle();
}

private void VerEncabezado()
{
    DataRow dr = null;
    string cadena_sql = "";

    cadena_sql = @"SELECT * 
                   FROM Facturas
                   WHERE codigo = {0}";

    cadena_sql = string.Format(cadena_sql, param_codigo);

    if (global.conn.SQLSelectDataRow(cadena_sql, ref dr))
    {
        txtCodigo.Text = dr["codigo"].ToString();
        txtNumeroFactura.Text = dr["numero_factura"].ToString();
        dtpFecha.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["fecha"]);
        cmbCodigoCliente.SelectedValue = Convert.ToInt32(dr["codigo_cliente"]);

        txtSubtotal.Text = Convert.ToDouble(dr["subtotal"]).ToString("###,###.00");
        txtImpuesto.Text = Convert.ToDouble(dr["impuesto"]).ToString("###,###.00");
        txtTotal.Text = Convert.ToDouble(dr["total"]).ToString("###,###.00");

    }
}
private void VerDetalle()
{
    string cadena_sql = "";
    DataTable dt = null;

    cadena_sql = @"SELECT 
                    fd.numero_linea
                    ,fd.codigo_producto
                    ,p.nombre as nombre_producto
                    ,fd.cantidad
                    ,fd.precio
                    ,(fd.cantidad * fd.precio) as total_item
                    FROM
                    FacturasDetalle fd
                    join
                    Productos p
                    on
                    fd.codigo_producto = p.codigo
                    WHERE
                    fd.codigo_factura = {0}
                    ";

    cadena_sql = string.Format(cadena_sql, param_codigo);

    if (global.conn.SQLSelectDataTable(cadena_sql, ref dt))
    {
        dgvDetalle.DataSource = dt;
    }


}


private void Totales()
{
    // Objetivo:
    // Recorrer el detalle, calcular total item
    // Sumarizar Subtotal, impuesto y total

    double cantidad = 0;
    double precio = 0;
    double total_item = 0;

    double subtotal = 0;
    double impuesto = 0;
    double total = 0;

    foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dgvDetalle.Rows)
    {
        cantidad = Convert.ToDouble(r.Cells["nCantidad"].Value);
        precio = Convert.ToDouble(r.Cells["nPrecio"].Value);

        total_item = cantidad * precio;

        r.Cells["nTotalItem"].Value = total_item;

        subtotal = subtotal + total_item;

    }

    // Calculamos impuesto y total
    impuesto = subtotal * 0.15;

    total = subtotal + impuesto;

    txtSubtotal.Text = subtotal.ToString("###,###.00");
    txtImpuesto.Text = impuesto.ToString("###,###.00");
    txtTotal.Text = total.ToString("###,###.00");


}


private void AdicionarProducto()
{
    try
    {
        int codigo_producto = 0;

        int indice_nuevo = 0;

        int numero_fila = 0;
        string nombre_producto = "";
        double precio_producto = 0;

        string cadena_sql = "";
        DataRow dr = null;

        frmProductos prods = new frmProductos();
        prods.modo_actual = frmLista.ModoApertura.Busqueda;
        prods.ShowDialog(this);

        codigo_producto = prods.codigo_seleccionado;

        if (codigo_producto > 0)
        {
            // Agregamos una fila

            cadena_sql = @"SELECT nombre, precio
                            FROM productos 
                            WHERE codigo = {0}";
            cadena_sql = string.Format(cadena_sql, codigo_producto);

            if (global.conn.SQLSelectDataRow(cadena_sql, ref dr))
            {
                nombre_producto = dr["nombre"].ToString();
                precio_producto = Convert.ToDouble(dr["precio"]);

                indice_nuevo = dgvDetalle.Rows.Add();

                dgvDetalle.Rows[indice_nuevo].Cells["nNumeroLinea"].Value = indice_nuevo + 1;
                dgvDetalle.Rows[indice_nuevo].Cells["nCodigoProducto"].Value = codigo_producto;
                dgvDetalle.Rows[indice_nuevo].Cells["sNombreProducto"].Value = nombre_producto;
                dgvDetalle.Rows[indice_nuevo].Cells["nCantidad"].Value = 1;
                dgvDetalle.Rows[indice_nuevo].Cells["nPrecio"].Value = precio_producto;

                dgvDetalle.Rows[indice_nuevo].Cells["nTotalItem"].Value = precio_producto;

                // Llamamos a la funcion de Totales
                Totales();
            }






        }



    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}

private void btnAdicionarProducto_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AdicionarProducto();
}

private void dgvDetalle_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    Totales();
}

private void frmFactura_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

protected override void AccionGuardar()
{
    if (param_codigo > 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Factura no se puede editar");
        return;
    }

    if (GuardarEncabezado())
    {
        GuardarDetalle();
    }
}

private bool GuardarEncabezado()
{
    try
    {
        DataRow dr = null;
        int codigo = 0;
        string cadena_sql = "";

        cadena_sql = @"INSERT INTO [dbo].[Facturas]
                   ([numero_factura],
                   [codigo_cliente],
                   [fecha],
                   [subtotal],
                   [impuesto],
                   [total])
             VALUES
                   (
                    {0},
                    {1},
                    '{2}',
                    {3},
                    {4},
                    {5})";


        cadena_sql = string.Format(
                    cadena_sql,
                    txtNumeroFactura.Text,
                    cmbCodigoCliente.SelectedValue,
                    dtpFecha.Value.ToString("yyyyMMdd"),
                    Convert.ToDouble(txtSubtotal.Text),
                    Convert.ToDouble(txtImpuesto.Text),
                    Convert.ToDouble(txtTotal.Text)
                    );

        if (global.conn.SqlExec(cadena_sql))
        {
            cadena_sql = @"SELECT MAX(codigo) as maximo
                           FROM Facturas";

            if (global.conn.SQLSelectDataRow(cadena_sql, ref dr))
            {
                codigo = Convert.ToInt32(dr["maximo"]);

                txtCodigo.Text = codigo.ToString();

                return true;

            }



         }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error al guardar encabezado: "
                            + global.conn.SQLError() );
        }


    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }

    return false;
}

private void GuardarDetalle()
{
    try
    {
        int codigo_factura = 0;
        string cadena_base = "";
        string cadena_sql = "";

        codigo_factura = Convert.ToInt32(txtCodigo.Text);

        cadena_base = @"INSERT INTO 
                        FacturasDetalle
                       (codigo_factura
                       ,numero_linea
                       ,codigo_producto
                       ,cantidad
                       ,precio)
                 VALUES
                       (
                        {0}
                        ,{1}
                        ,{2}
                        ,{3}
                        ,{4}
                        )";

        foreach(DataGridViewRow r in dgvDetalle.Rows)
        {
            cadena_sql = string.Format(cadena_base
                      , codigo_factura
                      , Convert.ToInt32(r.Cells["nNumeroLinea"].Value)
                      , Convert.ToInt32(r.Cells["nCodigoProducto"].Value)
                      , Convert.ToDouble(r.Cells["nCantidad"].Value)
                      , Convert.ToDouble(r.Cells["nPrecio"].Value)
                      );

            if (! (global.conn.SqlExec(cadena_sql)) )
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error al guardar detalle: " + global.conn.SQLError());
            }

        }

        MessageBox.Show("Factura Guardada con Exito");
        this.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Publica solo una pregunta al tiempo.

Answer (score 0):

Buenas aparentemente, como indica el mensaje de error, al hacer INSERT en la base de datos, no estás colocando todos los valores de las columnas, es posible que te falte añadir algún campo o que este, esté llegando como nulo. Asegúrate también que hayas definido claves primarias autoincrementables, para que no dependa del valor que coloques de entrada.